# Sticky header isn't scrolling in mobile mode

Tags: wordpress, mobile, scroll, header, sticky

Going into mobile mode and the sticky header won't scroll it will stay in fixed position.

Random poor attempts and throwing together bits of css.

This is the CSS for the sticky header currently. (I use it in a plugin but this is the css from the plugin)

```
#site-logo-inner, #site-header-inner {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
#site-header #site-logo #site-logo-inner a img {
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.fixed_sticky_active #site-header #site-logo #site-logo-inner a img {
    max-height: 50px!important;
} 

@media(min-width: 960px){
    .fixed_sticky_active #site-logo-inner {
        height: 74px!important;
    }
    .fixed_sticky_active #site-navigation-wrap .dropdown-menu >li >a {
        line-height: 74px!important;
        display: inline-block!important;
    }
    .fixed_sticky_active #site-header {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@media(max-width: 480px){
    .fixed_sticky_active #site-header {
        top: 0;
    }
    .fixed_sticky_active #site-header-inner {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

I have tried this;

```
@media(max-width: 480px){
    .fixed_sticky_active #site-header {
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow: auto;
        top: 0;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    .fixed_sticky_active #site-header-inner {
        padding: 0;
        max-height: 100vh;
        overflow: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
}
```

(Totally not sure what I'm doing but I saw it as a fix in another post, but didn't work :()

Comment: So I found I can make it scroll by just adding overflow:scroll; to the #site-header but then that makes it have a huge blank white area that's scrollable in the sticky header, and also adds a Scroll bar to the desktop sticky header along with the vertical huge blank white space.

Comment: Yay figured it out!!! I did; @media (max-width: 735px) {
    #site-header {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    max-height: 75vh;
    }
}